# What is the best practice for creating customized UI component in tornadofx?

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

i am new to JavaFX and tornadofx, and now i need to create some highly customized UI components(including submit button, text input field, password input field, datetime picker, dropdown selector etc) shown as the picture bellow:

[image]

so, what is the best practice for creating these components?
my question includes:

1. which super class my customized UI component should extend?
2. is there any existing example in tornadofx?
3. can i use bootstrap in my case? and if yes, how can i use bootstrap?

thanks
(this question also posted here: https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/issues/498)

Comment: Regarding the bootstrap related portion of your question, see: [Bootstrap with JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268062/bootstrap-with-javafx).

Comment: @jewelsea thanks for your suggestion, i will try later:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There really isn't anything TornadoFX specific to this process, but I have two recommendations:

Don't create a custom control unless you really need to. To add custom functionality to a Button or a TextField, install a custom skin instead.

If you really need a custom control, consider extending the Control class. For more layout centric components you might extend a layout instead, or simply Pane.

To learn more about custom components, consider reading this brilliant book:

[https://www.amazon.com/Mastering-JavaFX-Controls-Oracle-Press-ebook/dp/B00L3TF02K](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00L3TF02K)

Also check out these videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9xtOhdSx6k

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PPcM0E5yQw