# How to make text in WebView wrap?

Tags: java, css, javafx, webview

My application uses a `WebView` to display dynamic HTML that is generated on-the-fly during use of the program.

I am trying to ensure the content of the HTML is all displayed within the WebView without horizontal scrolling at all (vertical is fine). I have found many guides on how to make the WebView scale with the contents, but not the other way around.

Here is the code used to generate the HTML:

```
html
                .append("<head><style>\n")
                .append("   body {\n")
                .append("       font-size: ").append(Settings.getFontSize()).append("px;\n")
                .append("       font-family: ").append(Settings.getFontName()).append(";\n")
                .append("   }\n")
                .append("</style></head><body>\n");
```

Then, within the body, I load some proprietary text that I cannot post here. The text will often extend past the right side of the `WebView`:

[image]
* *I apologize for the obfuscation; proprietary information*

The WebView size cannot be increased to compensate. How do I set the style properly to allow for the text to wrap?

I have already tried setting the `width` of `body` to 100% and `word-wrap` to "normal."

Thank you.

**EDIT**
My question has nothing to do with Bootstrap. If bootstrap is required for simply fitting the contents of a `WebEngine` into the `WebView`, it would be out of the question; are there any other work-arounds?

Comment: Looks like you may need to use `Bootstrap` or some other framework that can manage this for you. Just a guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap with JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268062/bootstrap-with-javafx)

Comment: I can't imagine bringing in a heavy framework like Bootstrap should be required for such a basic functionality. And this definitely is not a duplicate as it has nothing in common with the question you linked to...

Comment: The linked question shows how to use `Bootstrap` in the `WebView`. `Bootstrap` does exactly what you are asking.

Comment: But calling it a duplicate question is not correct. I am not asking how to use Bootstrap in my application. Bootstrap may be a decent solution, but it is not the same question.

Comment: You can lead a horse to water but you can't make him drink.

Comment: I know, `Bootstrap` is just one solution. You can also obtain this using other frameworks.

Comment: I will look into Bootstrap. But to close my question claiming it has already been asked is wrong. Nothing in the question you posted even refers to text wrapping or fitting content into a `WebView`. I appreciate your suggestion but flagging this question and making sarcastic remarks is not helpful to anyone.

Comment: It says possible duplicate. Emphasis on possible. Four other people would have to agree with me. It does not have to refer to it. I know how `Bootstrap` works. I have used it a lot.

Comment: Another possible solution would be to keep up with the `WebView's` width and try to put `<br>` in your `HTML` in the correct place`. Seems complicated to me though.

Comment: Think about this way. An everyday browser can't do what you are asking without a frame work, but you think `WebView` can. I could be totally wrong, but.

Comment: I gave you an uptick in hopes that the JavaFX experts will come and have an answer for you. I think it's a good question. I just don't' think the solution is built into JavaFX.

Comment: Thank you. I know long before Bootstrap came along, websites were able to define a max width and the content would wrap. I have used Bootstrap as well, but I need to do this with straight HTML/CSS, if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the simple solution. `WebView` does already have this functionality by default. The issue was with my generated HTML; I was wrapping the offending text in the `<pre>` tag, which forced it to be rendered as one continuous line of text.

There is still an issue with 1 or 2 characters overflowing and causing horizontal scrolling, but I should be able to fix that with some CSS padding.

Comment: Haha no worries. I didn't include the `<pre>` in my question so that didn't help things either. Thanks for trying, though!